# I/O Operation on Closed File Error

Tags: python, file-io, runtime-error

So I'm writing this program which creates reads files using the open(). When I try to run the program is gives me the error: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file (line 18).

In every question I've seen on this topic, the issue always has to do with indentation. IE trying to operate on a file that was not opened in the same loop. I'm a bit rusty with my python, but the indentation looks just fine to me.

I was hoping someone could give it a quick look-over and let me know if the indentation is wrong, or otherwise if something else might be causing the error?
The code (error is commented):

```
sourceFile = 'test.html'
serviceTarget = "Plumbers & HVAC Experts"
cityTarget = "NJ"

services = {"Plumbers", "Air Conditioning Experts", "Drain Cleaning Experts"}
cities = {"Westfield", "Scotch Plains", "Clark"}

serviceNames = {"Plumbers":"plumbers", "Air Conditioning Experts":"ac", "Drain Cleaning Experts":"drain"}
totalPages = len(services)*len(cities)

for serviceRep in services:
    for cityRep in cities:
        outFileName = cityRep + " " + serviceNames[serviceRep] + ".html"
        outFileName = outFileName.replace(" ", "_");
        print("Writing " + outFileName + "...")
        infile = open(sourceFile)
        outfile = open(outFileName, 'w')
        for line in infile:   #This is the line giving me problems
            if serviceTarget in line:
                line = line.replace(serviceTarget,serviceRep)
            if cityTarget in line:
                line = line.replace(cityTarget,cityRep)
            outfile.write(line)
            infile.close()
            outfile.close()
        totalPages -= 1; 
        print("DONE -- " + str(totalPages) + " left to go")
```

Comment: youre referencing the opened file, you never did a `.read()` to get the contents, youre also trying to close the file multiple times in the loop.

Comment: @MikeRixWolfe `for line in infile` already reads the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like an indentation problem: do you really mean that `infile.close()` and `outfile.close()` belong to `for line in infile:` loop?

Comment: You are correct! I knew the answer was right in front of my face. Thank you for the second set of eyes :)

Comment: @user2779949 I usually add a blank line after a block to make it more visually indented, that would help to see that `infile.close()` is at the wrong block.